# Operator '+' can't be applied to operands of types 'decimal' and 'double' - NCalc

Tags: c#, .net

Estou a usar a lib NCalc

Uma simples formula como "Abs(-1) + Cos(2)" dá a seguinte excepção:

> Operator '+' can't be applied to operands of types 'decimal' and 'double'

Porquê? Como resolver?

O calculo esta a ser executado da seguinte forma:

```
new Expression("Abs(-1) + Cos(2)").Evaluate()
```

A única discussão relacionada no site do projecto é um pouco antiga e fala sobre editar o codigo fonte https://ncalc.codeplex.com/discussions/346702

Comment: A sua resposta não é construtiva. Apenas traduziu o texto da excepção. A minha questão prende-se com o facto de Math.Abs(-1)+Math.Cos(2) functionar em C# mas não na biblioteca NCalc. Se nunca usou nem conhece a biblioteca nem devia estar comentando aqui.

Comment: ok, sem problemas.

Comment: @Omni e todos. Por favor não atirem sugestões para o ar. Se nunca usaram o NCalc não vão compreender a minha questão.
1º Não posso passar -1m e 2m pois não são números válidos.
2º Não são os parametros de Abs e Cos que têm o problema. É a soma do resultado de Abs e Cos

Comment: Uma das funções, `Abs` ou `Cos`, está retornando um valor `decimal` e outra está retornando um `double`. Acredito que se você tem acesso ao fonte da lib seria melhor alterar o tipo de retorno de uma das funções para evitar o erro ou utilizar algum recurso de conversão de tipos se ela possuir.

Comment: @RichardDias, a lib é open source. Já coloquei a questão no [codeplex](https://ncalc.codeplex.com/discussions/613634)

Não tenho conhecimento suficiente para tentar perceber se é um problema do código ou se estarei a fazer alguma coisa errado do meu lado.

Comment: Acredito que seja da lib ou uma má utilização dela pela sua parte. Você passa uma `string` para o construtor da class `Expression` e essa string é avaliada e transformada em uma fórmula correto?

Comment: Acho que você já tem a resposta na sua pergunta: https://ncalc.codeplex.com/discussions/346702 Agora é colocar as mãos na massa e alterar o código fonte para corrigir este problema

Comment: Não entendo de NCALC, mas sua expressão está entre aspas duplas, pelo que eu entendo isso seria uma concatenação e não uma soma, não uma expressão aritmética.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe um problema com a lib NCalc que já está corrigido no codigo fonte.

http://ncalc.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/5a719518101d

esta revisão não está disponível como um binário.

Comment: Criei um clone no [github](https://github.com/pitermarx/ncalc-edge), liguei ao [AppVeyor](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/pitermarx/ncalc-edge) E publiquei no [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NCalc-Edge/) uma versão mais actulizada.

Também [iniciei](https://github.com/pitermarx/ncalc2) um novo [projecto](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/pitermarx/ncalc2) que pretende [actualizar](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NCalc2) para o antlr4

Answer (score 2):

Não existe nenhum problema com a lib NCalc, a questão é que um método retorna Decimal e o outro retorna Double. O compilador .NET não permite operações entre estes dois tipos de objeto devido ao fato de a precisão dos dois serem muito diferentes.

O correto é converter o resultado de um dos métodos para o tipo de dados do outro método.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        double dbl = 1;
        decimal dec = 2;

        // Neste exemplo converti o valor double para decimal.
        var result = Convert.ToDecimal(dbl) + dec;

        Console.WriteLine(result);

        // Esta operação retorna a exceção Operator '+' can'tbe applied to operands of types 'decimal' and 'double'
        Console.WriteLine(dbl + dec);
    }
}
```

Comment: Existe sim um problema com a lib. Está corrigido no codigo fonte mas não na última versão do binário
http://ncalc.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/5a719518101d

Comment: Na realidade o que falta é sair um build definitivo com a correção, mais da forma que foi proposta resolve temporariamente até a liberação dos arquivos binários.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

class Program
{
  public void Main()
  {
    double a  = 1;
    decimal b = 2;
    a = Convert.ToDouble(1);
    b = Convert.ToDouble(2);

    int valor = a + b;

    Console.Write(int.ToString());

    return 0;
  }
}
```